# Ubuntu 20.04 is slow to open programs

Tags: 20.04

I recently (this month) created my computer and installed Ubuntu 20.04. Recently, I've noticed it's slow to respond and takes ages to open up programs after they've been closed for a while:

- Firefox: 7-10 seconds
- Settings -> keyboard shortcuts: 10-13 seconds

and few others. Is there anything I can do diagnose this issue?

Computer specs:

- Gnome 3
- AMD Ryzen 9 3900x 12-core/24 threads
- AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
- 1 TB Sabrent Rocket
- 32 GB DDR4